# Currently analysing a sample of the vjw0rm js malware but I don't know how to find the hidden ioc

Tags: javascript, malware

So for the last couple of days I have been practicing some basic malware analysis on mainly macro malware like Agent Tesla but this time I am trying to figure out how solve the logic of the vjworm javascript malware and so far I have managed to deobfuscate the code using a combination of both manual deobfuscation and an online tool.

This is the sample in it's deobfuscated form `https://pastebin.com/qRBKix6V`

I am not able to post the entire thing here on Stackoverflow so I posted it on pastebin because it's just too large for the post limit of 30000 characters so I will post a snippet of the code instead and it's a piece of the code I am struggling to wrap my head around where it looks to be base64
and I did try convert it into text using a base64 to text online tool and I was promptly told that this was actually code and that I should convert to the bin format and I could read the output before I downloaded it and it was just a bunch of random letters with no meaning at all
What does this mean?.

```
function t() {
  var Nd = ["W68xWPnGW59PWQiEnaC", "yMeBqSoNWPxdO8kT", "omkdW6ddQq", "q2XVC2u", "W7/dPCkWWPpdNfldVG", "WOHnWONcTtXLWPH+WQPb", "sSkzfq", "A3LWzsaVDhiGiG", "vbVdSSk7WOK", "Evz3tuK", "fSoHxmk9C1ldPq", "WOtcLSozW6S", "W7ebWPBcRaCxW5BcJrn0", "Ahr0CdOVl2DYyq", "atP8ssW", "gL3cMG", "C3bSAxq", "u2XLzxa", "B3bLBG", "tfNdJGddR8oFqSkHW7u", "W4RdPCo4aN/cIw9Ifmk4WPv1", "Dg9tDhjPBMC", "BsS0ga", "rhhcT3lcKXpcT8keW4tdMG", "jvjNtMuL", "WRpcTCoyW6/cQq", "mhWZFdr8mxWY", "ue9tva", "W5SibaddMmkMumo4", "mZmWt3Lsrvfe", "FY3dPHZcOcdcJ8kSWQJdQa", "lrJcQ8oRWQFdGSoaWPW6W4y", "aCo/fvxdJMuaD8oyW6C", "W5nKW68+ntGvEConeZ0", "W4pcJSkO", "Dub7or8", "hGnwAbvOcSo6W79/", "BgVcGwJcLG", "uMvNv3jPDgu", "xhjVB3rCC2vJDq", "W6LEA19k", "W4TgW6VdR3i", "WOTqgrldVmkDEmo4", "W7FcVSk1CmoBpW", "BuDAtKS", "WPNcNhqRWQ0", "t8kAztlcQmkrhW", "W5tdLahdNCoEW7KYmSkacW", "fSo0W4xcMN0XW5TDi2S", "tCoEWRJcVutcP2SJn8oMWQi", "twLJCM9ZB2z0xa", "WO9uwKZcHmk0CSoniSkIW5W", "WRZdJGtdI8od", "ef/dM8kau8olW6jFn8k6", "yxbWBhK", "jxZcVSkgWPe", "F8oPvW", "mJy0vhv2vgXi", "WRtdVMm1", "qCk4m8kNAM3dSHRdIq", "F2RcQG", "pCo5W6e7oaysu8oX", "hCodowFdS8osqSo5y8kogKFdVq", "WRyAkmk0kHuHFwS", "nxW0FdH8mW", "shHSz1O", "sXpdUmkUWO3dNCo7k8oWza", "WRiwj8kRlHa", "yMvRBKC", "AxrLBq", "WRJdH8ouWQRdKa", "u2HLBgWUqxbWBa", "W6PdW50", "W53dOCk0WPC", "oCk5xwJcSq", "atapCSoCWQxdMSk6", "zLDLuhG", "juVdHCoXW67cJxZdVSkLW4y", "ntG1odD2qKrRzNG", "ntuWmtK1DxjtC2nx", "we1msfruua", "ruPUEhu", "BG9MW58qWPJcPfddK8kt", "W7KibqBdKa", "jGVcQSk0W5JdLmkUi8kR", "W6nfA11+", "uxvPDa", "d8kDEvxcKa", "renDcdS", "W5/dVc7dVmo0", "WR5keSkhW7jdyCkca8o0sq0d", "WOVcVCkaDGS", "jedcRmo+W5NcNSoXoCoVCmkVWP8", "Bw92zu5LEhq", "wefJW5mcWP/cQeZdGSoy", "Ffz8", "EujSyvi", "yxrPBMDtExn0zq", "zgVcOwS", "h2hcOCkxWRRdOmkwqW", "DuPcfZ/cP3y", "rJ0XdLO", "CSonCJy+", "jJitWOhdHcldS8opbmkp", "rMLSzq", "ChnHBg1Zltu1", "betdKmkftSoC", "W6ZdTmkfWPhdMq", "uhjVz3jHBurHDa", "mNWWFdf8n3W2Fa", "FwPxW4BcMW", "v2LUzg93C1XdDq", "WPqHWRe", "xe1Py3jVC29MDa", "vxL4Cu0", "rgLZCgXHEu5HBq", "wuvt", "WQtcH8kLWPbpydzfWPRcVa", "W7vcW6BdQ3a", "u2nODgfZA3mGlW", "sw5ZDgfUy2vZtW", "odCZsgXrs2Do", "qSk+mvdcUa", "yxrfBMq", "vwDoC1u", "W7HfW5KHW6KFW6u", "zwXS", "z8kNcNTsWR3dKSoJWRFcVG", "u0XbD2O", "CMvWBgfJzq", "W6LiW4VcRXvNW47cJfro", "W4rrW7C", "yuXutgq", "v1nJCMLWDc5tAa", "W6ddVW7dJSoJ", "r1DNs2K", "wgDZtwq", "t3bLBLrLEhrgAq", "t3rYweK", "W5tdRSkoWRJdNa", "xfnVzNr3yxjLxa", "tqpcPt3cRZjFWP3dHH0", "zmkafgVcRSk1W6vYrmkn", "fmoGDSkksfNdGqK", "WONcU8k4WPbU", "qLFdR8k9uG", "qmoqwX8CW7bgzq", "Emo4W4hcKvS1W58EAq", "seTmtvXtt0zuvW", "uKvhx1nA", "CML0EwnLBNrLCG", "DCkclIO", "DgvTCa", "lK5fvfXgCMfTzq", "nKD6B3fbra", "BgXUvLa", "g2/dQSor", "mZq0mtjzv0rHwuG", "oCkNvf7cSsn5tu5t", "y29Kzeu", "udDfs09xqJzhsa", "rmo2W6xcTKK", "v3jPDgu"];
```

This is the malware sample in it's obfuscated form `https://pastebin.com/xukFtPT7`

My main goal here is to get an understanding about how the code functions and how it eventually get's to the ioc like ip adresses and domain names.

So far I have done some research around this malware but I found very little regarding how to reverse engineer this malware and the only resource I found did not have the same code as me.

I am by no means an expert at reverse engineering malware and I am not a master programmer by any means but I am able to read,write basic programs.
But on the other hand I have watched many tutorials and read many resources regarding malware from different families and how to best analyse them using a combination of both tools and manual malware analysis both static and dynamic.

What should I do now?